# Getting the ending position of CString

Tags: c++, substring, cstring

How can I find the position of the end of a CString? I am trying the

```
int end = str.Find(L'\n');
```

but it returns -1. I want in particular to get a substring from a CString from some position in the CString till the end of it. The problem is I cannot get the position of the end. Any suggestion?

Comment: Not every string ends with '\n'. With `CString.GetLength()` you can get the length of the string, which is also the end of the string.

Comment: Not only do strings not end with a \n, they may contain any number of \n. e.g. "Hello\nWorld\n". Which CString are you using? See: http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/clibrary/cstring/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `CString::Mid(beginPos)`, as `CString sub = str.Mid(begin)`. It will return the substring that starts at `beginPos` and stretches all the way to the end of the string. If you do want the string's length, use `GetLength`. Searching for `'\n'` is pointless, as it might not be in the string, and if it does, it might not be at the end of that string.

Answer (score 0):

Looking up the character `L'\n'` searches for a line break rather the the 'end' of the string. 
Doesn't CString support a size() or length() method, you can use to get the overall length that can be used to calculate the length of the substring you want?

Answer (score 0):

First, the string is zero terminated, so at least you should be finding '\0' instead of '\n'.

In fact, you chould check the size of the string and decrease it by 1, and that's the index position of the last char.